# What is the topic ~/world_stats?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am following this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=topics_subscribed&cat=transport) . It teaches me to write a program to listen on the topic ~/world_stats.
I did and it worked. However, when I run $ gz topic -l, I cannot find a topic named ~/world_stats. So what is ~/world_stats? and what does the tilde '~' mean here? And what is
'ConstWorldStatisticsPtr'?

The following is the listener.cpp files for your reference:

```
#include <gazebo/transport/transport.hh>
#include <gazebo/msgs/msgs.hh>
#include <gazebo/gazebo.hh>

#include <iostream>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Function is called everytime a message is received.
void cb(ConstWorldStatisticsPtr &_msg)
{
  // Dump the message contents to stdout.
  std::cout << _msg->DebugString();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int _argc, char **_argv)
{
  // Load gazebo
  gazebo::setupClient(_argc, _argv);

  // Create our node for communication
  gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  node->Init();

  // Listen to Gazebo world_stats topic
  gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = node->Subscribe("~/world_stats", cb);

  // Busy wait loop...replace with your own code as needed.
  while (true)
    gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(10);

  // Make sure to shut everything down.
  gazebo::shutdown();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8231/what-is-the-topic-%7E/world_stats?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`~/world_stats` gives you statistics about the world, such as the time elapsed and the paused state.

- The type of the messages being published is `gazebo::msgs::WorldStatistics`. [Here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/9576b4d90116d705563537883b1c96db821b2c63/gazebo/msgs/world_stats.proto) you can see all the message fields. `ConstWorldStatisticsPtr` is the same as `boost::shared_ptr<const gazebo::msgs::WorldStatistics>`.
- The tilde `~` is shorthand for the default world. If you're running the default world, when you do `$ gz topic -l`, you'll see a list of topics all starting with `/gazebo/default` and one of them is `/gazebo/default/world_stats`, which corresponds to the `~/world_stats` you're subscribing to.
- You can run `$ gz topic -e /gazebo/default/world_stats`, to see all fields of the message printed out as the simulation is running.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lays](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14571/lays/) on 2019-08-18**:
great! but who publish the ~/world_stats? i did not find it in the source code.
thanks